# NSInvocationOperation - Does not call method on a different thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsinvocationoperation

So I have a service clint class that has a method called fetch.
I am invoking this method using NSInvocationOperation. and when I check the thread it seems like it's callin the mthod on the main thread. Isn't the whole point of using NSInvocationOperation to run things asynchronously?

Invoking method

```
ServiceClient *client = [[ServiceClient alloc] init];
NSInvocationOperation *invocatopnOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:client selector:@selector(fetch) object:nil];
[invocatopnOperation start];
```

The method in service client

```
- (void)fetch
{
    if ([[NSThread currentThread] isEqual:[NSThread mainThread]])
    {
        NSLog(@"NOOOOOO");
    }
     ............
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From NSInvocationOperation class reference:

> The NSInvocationOperation class is a concrete subclass of NSOperation
>   that manages the execution of a single encapsulated task specified as
>   an invocation. You can use this class to initiate an operation that
>   consists of invoking a selector on a specified object. **This class
>   implements a non-concurrent operation**.

This means that in order to perform an operation asynchronously you need to add it to an operation queue.